# Markup to define conditionally-required function arguments?

Tags: python, markup, type-hinting

I'm pretty sure the answer to this is, "No," but I'm going to ask just in case. Is there a way to specify a conditionally-required function argument in Python using type hint notation or via some other external markup language? For example:

```
def my_function(cond: bool, arg1: int=0, arg2: int=0):
    if cond:
        return arg1
    else:
        return arg2
```

As you can see, depending on the value of `cond`, only  `arg1` or `arg2` is required, but not both. Is there a way to document conditionally-required arguments?

Here's my use-case. I'm building an application that has a lot of co-dependent functions. The functions that can be executed depends upon which arguments the user has provided (and if certain arguments meet certain conditions). While I COULD hard-code this logic into the front-end of the application, it would be easier to let the front end dynamically interpret the required arguments from sort of markup language. Does such a thing exist?

Let me know if this makes sense. I'm happy to provide a better example if necessary.

**EDIT:** This example is a bit closer to reality, though I seriously simplified these functions. I've got about 60 functions like this that are all intertwined and have some fairly simple conditionally-required arguments (things like `if <val> == 0` and such). I'd like to be able to make it easy to add new functions in the future and let my UI automatically prompt the user for required fields as necessary instead of having to hard-code this logic into the front-end.

```
def density(viscosity: float, gas_grav: float, temp: float=0, press: float=0):
    if viscosity == 0:
        den = 1.495 * 10 ** -3 * (press * (gas_grav)) / (temp + 459.67))

    else:
        den = ((141.5 / (viscosity + 131.5) * 62.428) + 0.0136) / 62.428

    return den

def temperature(temp_grad: float, surface_temp: float, depth: float):
    temp = surface_temp + temp_grad * depth

    return temp

def pressure(press_grad: float, depth: float):
    press = press_grad * depth

    return press
```

It doesn't HAVE to be in Python. If there's a logical markup language that fits, that would work, too. I could come up with my own thing, but something standard(ish) is best if that happens to exist.

Comment: You might be able to do this with `@overload`?  Would need to see an example that's a bit closer to reality.

Comment: @Samwise - added a better example. I can give you more if you'd like, but it would just be more of the same (intertwined functions that all call one another and have conditional requirements based on internal logic).